# ARCore: How to make my app available on GPlay only to devices that support Depth API?

Tags: java, android, google-play, arcore, google-play-console

I have an app that uses Depth API.

As mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Depth API is not supported by all devices that support ARCore.

How can I specify in my Manifest (or elsewhere) that my app requires a device compatible with Depth API ? Indeed, I don't want to see my app to be downloaded by users who can't use it!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth API-supported devices
Only devices that are depth-supported should be able to discover depth-required apps in the Google Play Store. Discovery should be limited to depth-supported devices when:

A core part of the experience relies on depth
There is no graceful fallback for the parts of the app that use depth
To limit distribution of your app in the Google Play Store to devices that support the Depth API, add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml, in addition to the AndroidManifest.xml changes described in the Enable ARCore guide:

```
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth" />
```

reference:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/developer-guide

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no way of explicitly telling your app not to be downloaded based on anything other than SDK version directly through your Manifest.

What you could do, is that the Google Play Console has a section where you can manually include/exclude devices into the pool of devices that can find you app in the store. I do have to warn you that **this process is VERY manual**, both for exclusions and inclusions altogether.

Therefore, what you could do, is to make a list of the devices that you want to support on your own, and then reflect this list by blacklisting the rest of the devices that you don't want to support directly through your Google Play Console.

Comment: Thanks. If you are right (I am afraid you are...), this is indeed a very manual process and not acceptable as there are many submodels for every model and really hard to know if each submodel is compatible with Depth API. Moreover, there will be many compatible devices added in the future and I don't want to spend hours each week or month to check what new models are compatible in order to add them in the console. This feature is a must-have that should be proposed by the ARCore team. I hope that they will do this... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah I absolutely agree with you. I actually had to do this myself at some point but we changed our mind pretty quickly for that project. I think your best option is to find a way of figuring out if a certain device can use your app or not and to display some kind of message on app launch. Hope you figure it out!